# Control template literal types that match in multiple places

Tags: typescript, generics, template-literals

I have an asset loader that supports many different file extensions (`.png`, `.svg`, `.mp4`), which are used for validation when loading assets:

```
type ending = 'png' | 'svg' |'mp4';

function load(path: `${string}.${ending}`) {}
```

This lets you load `cat.png` but not `dog.mp3`, which is desired. However, I have a more complex loader:

```
type EndingsToTypes = {
    png: HTMLImageElement,
    svg: HTMLOrSVGElement,
    mp4: HTMLVideoElement
}

function load<T extends keyof EndingsToTypes>(path: `${string}.${T}`): EndingsToTypes[T] {

}
```

Which loads the images and returns the correct type of data.

This works fine, however, it can not handle:

```
const file = load('./files/cat.png')
```

(`file` is the union type of all the possible values inside `EndingsToType`)

How do I force it to use the last part of the string as `T`?

Comment: Please consider adhering to standard naming conventions; non-primitive type names tend to be in UpperPascalCase, so `Ending` and `EndingsToTypes` are more conventional.  Also, you say "it cannot handle", which is not descriptive enough to be a [mre].  If there is a problem, you should mention explicitly what the problem is (e.g., "I expect `file` to be of type XXX when it is in fact of type YYY according to intellisense").

Comment: This is an interesting failure; I wonder if it's a bug or a design limitation.  My workaround here would be to explicitly walk the type checker through the string and explicitly grab only the part after the last dot.  Like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXQdDN) shows.  If that fully addresses your question I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I opened https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49839 to see whether they consider this a bug or intentional, by the way.